# Superscript (R) throughout workbook - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook containing 10-15 sheets, throughout the workbook I have a number of registered trademark symbols, typed as text in cells (displayed as ®). I need a macro that can run through the content of all cells, find the ® and superscript that part of the cell.

I have made a draft below, but I get a 'Object variable or with block variable not set' error.

```
Sub Superscript()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets
    sht.Activate
    Dim Match As Variant, start As Variant, pos As Long, cnt As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Match = .Cells.Find("®", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)    ' Find the first match in the active sheet
        If Not Match Is Nothing Then
            start = Match.Address
            Do
               cnt = Len(Match.Value) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Match.Value, "®", ""))
               pos = InStr(Match.Value, "®")
            Do
                Match.Characters(pos, 1).Font.Superscript = True
                pos = InStr(pos + 1, Match.Value, "®")
                cnt = cnt - 1
               Loop While cnt > 0
               Set Match = .Cells.FindNext(Match)
            Loop While Not Match Is Nothing And Match.Address <> start
        End If
    End With
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get nothing from a [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) once you've established that you have found something unless you change the content significantly enough that the Find will not Find it again. You are not actually changing the content, just modifying the formatting. The check against the address is to make sure you do not go through all of the matches and end up back at the beginning which you will eventually do but the .Find is never going to be nothing.

```
Sub Superscript()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Range, frst As String, pos As Long, cnt As Integer

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        With sht
            Set fnd = .Cells.Find(Chr(174), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)    ' Find the first match in the active sheet
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                frst = fnd.Address
                Do
                    pos = InStr(1, fnd.Value, Chr(174))
                   Do
                        fnd.Characters(start:=pos, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
                        pos = InStr(pos + 1, fnd.Value, Chr(174))
                   Loop While pos > 0
                   Set fnd = .Cells.FindNext(after:=fnd)
                Loop While fnd.Address <> frst
            End If
        End With
    Next sht

End Sub
```

I don't like to see variables with the same names as reserved words so I have made some superficial changes to the var names as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. When running your code above I get the same error for the line "Loop While fnd.Address <> frst"